# How to accept cookies when using a webservice - Android?

Tags: android, web-services, cookies, android-studio

I'm trying to send HTTP Post requests to my webservice. It seems to work, however the cookies are not enabled.

I tried to import `android.webkit.CookieManager` in my Application and then use this code :

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
```

I get an error telling me that CookieManager cannot be instancied.

Is there a way to allow cookies when sending a POST request ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `CookieManager` is a single instance class it mean no object can be created using `new` keyword. Try using `CookieManager.getInstance()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for webview cookies

```
 CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setCookie(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,android.webkit.ValueCallback

Comment: no it wont work without webview. In that case  ,  you need to store your cookie and then add it to the http header . what are you using to make web service call